Can we chant the Hanuman Chalisa outside of the temple?
I have taken up chanting Hanuman Chalisa during my daily puja and have been doing it for some time now. But recently I came across an article that says, to never chant Hanuman Chalisa anywhere else except in temple.
Is this where Hanuman Chalisa should be chanted? Does mispronounced Hanuman Chalisa have any negative effects? Will it displease Hanumanji if we were to chant in our home?

There is no such specific rule as to chant it only in the temples, feel free to chant it anywhere you wish to chant.

Can you link the article, please?

It is composed by Tulsidas. You won't find rules on how to chant it in scripture
